# Geolocation in Safari 9 always returning Position Unavailable

Tags: javascript, safari, geolocation

I'm building an app where I need to get the user's location. To do this I have a click event attached to a button, which then calls

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getVenues, handleError);
```

This works as expected on Chrome and Firefox, and the `getVenues` function is run after I grant access to my location. On Safari, after granting access the `handleError` function is immediately called.

This happens on both my local and production server, both of which use HTTPS. My computer is on a wifi connection. Safari Version 9.1.2 (11601.7.7). I have looked through some of the other posts related to Geolocation in Safari and none of the solutions have worked so far.

I have tried passing options to `getCurrentPosition` to increase the `timeout` and `maximumAge` but with no luck.

Here's my full code example:

```
$("#nearby-find").on('click', function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getVenues, handleError);
});

var getVenues = function(position) {
  console.log(position);
};

var handleError = function(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Clicking the button initiates the Geolocation access request but immediately after clicking Accept the `handleError` function is called with an error code of 2 (Position Unavailable).

Are there other issues/bugs/gotchas with Safari Geolocation I need to check?

Comment: Apparently there are security preferences that can cause that; are you sure that the "Location Services" are enabled? Other than that, geolocation code has to be able to handle failure anyway, since people might say "no" to the popup.

Comment: Wow, Safari wasn't on the Enable Location Services list. Is that the default - that Safari needs to be explicitly granted access to Location Services via Preferences?

Comment: I guess; I'm not a Mac user. I just googled :)

Comment: I came across that too and assumed (incorrectly) there was no way Safari wasn't allowed to access to Location Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari is not on the list of apps in the Enable Location Services list in System Preferences. You'll need to go into System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab, and make sure Safari is on the Enable Location Services list.

[image]