# Geolocation on safari not working (no permission prompt)

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, geolocation, html5-canvas

I have a code that gets the geolocation of the user after they click a button and approve access to their geolocation.

For some reason that prompt is not given in safari (did test with multiple devices).
There seems to be a standard "access denied" signal sent.

Information I find through google is contradictory.

Question: is it possible to get geolocation of a user with safari or does safari block this always?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Safari is on the list of apps in the Enable Location Services list in System Preferences.

[Geolocation in Safari 9 always returning Position Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372870/geolocation-in-safari-9-always-returning-position-unavailable)

Also make sure that in the privacy tab, the "Deny without prompting" option is off.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8itc.png

Comment: Great answer.  You could eliminate the "See: " to make it flow better but it's minor point.